# Php Custom Function For Mysql Query Not Working

Tags: php, function

I have created two functions one for connecting to MySQL database and one for running a specific query.
I enter the database name as parameter for first function to connect to the database, this works fine, but my problem is with the second one.
2nd function returns the `$result` from running a query, but when I use `mysql_fetch_array` with the `$result`, it gives one output even if it supposed to give more than one.
As I am no php expert so i can't find the solution. Please help me.

Here is the code:

**File Function.php**

```
<?php
function myconnect($data)
{
  $db_host='localhost';
  $db_user='root';
  $db_pwd='';
  $data=$data;
  $dbc = mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_user,$db_pwd,$data) or die (mysql_error());
  return $dbc;
}

function runquery($db,$table,$tcol,$tid)//(databse,table,column_name,identifier)
{
  $dbc=myconnect($db);
  $query="SELECT *FROM ".$table." WHERE ".$tcol."=".$tid." ORDER BY first_name ASC";
  $result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
  return $result;
}
?>
```

**File test.php**

```
<?php
  require_once('testfunc.php');
  $result= runquery('user','user_basic','user_type','1');
  //runquery('database','table','col','id')/
  while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  { 
    echo '<strong>First Name:</strong>' . $row['first_name'] . '<br/>';
  }
?>
```

If I am doing all wrong then suggest me a better way :-)

Comment: your question is not clear enough. Could you elaborate a better description of what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: *FROM should be * FROM... problem if $table doesn't have a column called first_name... look to use mysqli rather than mysql; or (even better) pdo

Comment: This code could use a [review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function myconnect($db)
{
    /*Removed redundant - single use variables*/

    /*DB name was passed to the client_flags parameter of mysql_connect instead of mysql_select_db*/
    $dbc = mysql_connect("localhost", "root","") or die (mysql_error());
    /*Inserted Line*/
    mysql_select_db($data);
    return $dbc;
}
```

Currently you're not selecting  a database - equivalent of USE DATABASE db_name.

Couple of syntax changes and function definition

```
function runquery($db,$table,$tcol,$tid)//(databse,table,column_name,identifier)
{
    $dbc=myconnect($db);
    /*Query and link identifier were in the wrong order*/
    return mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ".$table." WHERE ".$tcol."=".$tid." ORDER BY first_name ASC", $doc);
}
```

Finally a couple of syntax changes, function calls

```
require_once('testfunc.php');
$result= runquery('user','user_basic','user_type','1');
/*fetch associateive array of result during iteration*/
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{ 
    echo '<strong>First Name:</strong>' . $row['first_name'] . '<br/>';
}
```

Comment: you should not use the mysql extension and instead should use the mysqli extension as it is _improved_

Comment: I haven't read up on it yet. Once I've had a chance see the relevance to the question I'll edit my answer. Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 2):

A quick glance shows that in your function *runquery*

```
SELECT *FROM
```

should be

```
SELECT * FROM
```

note the space after the *

**EDIT :** 
I also notice you are using *mysqli_fetch_array* and this is not a valid mysqli method. You are right in using the mysqli extension over mysql but you should look more into [statement fetch](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php) to solve this issue. The link I provided give a procedural example that should work for what you need.